# How to convert dates to numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time, format

I have some variables like these:

```
a(1)=00:26:00
a(2)=744:32:00
a(3)=8040:33:00
```

I want to convert them to numbers, so I use the datenum command.
The biggest number should be 8040:33:00, but look what happens.

```
datenum(a([1 2 3]))

ans =

1.0e+005 *

7.3487
7.3485
7.3486
```

But if I don´t calculate a(1):

```
datenum(a([2 3]))

ans =

1.0e+005 *

7.3490
7.3520
```

That´s the results that I want to get. I think that the problem is that a(2) and a(3) have more than 24hours but I haven´t found any way to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: You mean, `a{1} = '00:26:00'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not give us your actual input. Having

```
a(1)=00:26:00
a(2)=744:32:00
a(3)=8040:33:00
```

means `a` holds three zeroes. (`doc colon` explains why.)

If my guess as to what you're actually doing is right, you should be able to use

```
cellfun(@datenum, a)
```

I haven't checked deeply, but the behavior looks a bit surprising, indeed. You might want to contact MathWorks Support and file a bug report.

Comment: SOLVED. Christopher Creutzig was right. With the function cellfun it works perfectly. Thank you very much.